# which encoding to use for genetic algorithm?

Tags: c, genetic-algorithm

I want to code a genetic algorithm in C for optimizing a function of 10 variables (x1 to x10). However I am not able to figure out which encoding I should use. I have mostly seen binary encoding being used in example but the variables in my case can take real values. Also, is value encoding  a good option for these types of problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A genetic algorithm is best used when two answers that are pretty close to optimal will make something else pretty close to optimal when combined. The problem with a pure binary encoding is that if you don't check your crossover you end up getting two answers which may not have all that much to do with the original answers.

That said, this is only really an issue if your number of variables is very small and the amount of data in your variables is large. As far as picking an encoding, it's more of an art than a science and it depends on your problem. I would suggest going with an encoding that fits the amount of precision you want. With 10 variables you won't got that far wrong however you encode it, an 8-bit ASCII encoder would probably work fine.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

For real valued problems I would suggest to try CMA-ES or another ES variant. CMA-ES certainly is the current state of the art for real-valued problems. It is designed to find good solutions in multidimensional problems quickly. There are implementations available on [Hansen's page](https://www.lri.fr/~hansen/cmaes_inmatlab.html). There's also a C# implementation in the work for [HeuristicLab](http://dev.heuristiclab.com/trac/hl/core/blog/abeham/cmaes). Evolution strategies are algorithms that were specifically designed for real-valued optimization problems. They are very similar to genetic algorithms (both were invented around the same time, but in different places). The main distinction is that for ES the main driver is mutation and it features a clever adaption of the mutation strength. Without this adaption the (local) optimum cannot be located in time. CMA-ES is easy to configure, all it needs is the initial standard deviation and optionally the population size (otherwise there's a formula that estimates this given the problem size).

Genetic algorithms can of course also be applied, but you have to use some specific operators which are able to mutate variables only with very small degree. For example there's the Breeder Genetic Algorithm from Mühlenbein. In general however genetic algorithms are more suited for problems that need a right combination of things. E.g. which items to include in a knapsack problem or which functions and terminals to combine to a formula (genetic programming). Less for problems, where you need to find the right value for something. Although of course there are variants of the genetic algorithm to solve these, look for Real coded Genetic Algorithm (RCGA or RGA).

Another algorithm suited for real-valued problems is Particle Swarm Optimization, but in my opinion it is harder to configure. I'd start with [SPSO-2011](http://www.particleswarm.info/Programs.html) the 2011 standard PSO.

If your problem contains integer variables choices become more difficult. Evolution strategies do not perform so well when variables are discrete, because the adaptation schemes for integer variables are different. A genetic algorithm becomes an interesting first-choice algorithm again.